# Automation scripts developed on 32 bit, can edit and update on 64 bit?

Tags: java, selenium

In project, I have developed automated scripts using 32 bit set (OS win 7, Java, Eclipse). Now I have got a situation where I should switch to 64 bit environment (OS win 7, Java, Eclipse).

My question is here: Can we edit and update scripts on 64 bit platform which are developed on 32 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "scripts" you mean "Java source files" then yes, you can edit them regardless of the platform.

Comment: Yes these are automated scripts which are java source files. but my worry is 32 bit and 64 bit. will be there any problem in future updating scripts on 64 bit?

Comment: Java source files are just UTF-8 text, they're not affected by 32 or 64bit differences.